# SFML Rotation around the Center of an Object

Tags: c++, sfml

So I have this code here:

```
void Star::createStar(){
sf::CircleShape star1(r,50);
star1.setPosition(x,y);
sf::Texture* t = CreateTexture(256,256);
star1.setTexture(t,false);
star=star1;
std::cout << "Done!"<<std::endl;
}
void Star::update(){
star.setOrigin(x-(.5*r),y-(.5*r));

star.rotate(0.01);
}
```

and I want the star to rotate around it's center, but I may be doing calculations wrong, but it seems to rotate around the same point that it would even if I didn't declare the center.

EDIT:: I fixed it the star.setOrigin() should haev arameters r,r!

Comment: please submit your solution and select it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct code

```
void Star::createStar(){
sf::CircleShape star1(r,50);
star1.setPosition(x,y);
sf::Texture* t = CreateTexture(256,256);
star1.setTexture(t,false);
star=star1;
std::cout << "Done!"<<std::endl;
}
void Star::update(){
//star.setOrigin(x-(.5*r),y-(.5*r));
//no need to set origin
star.rotate(0.01);
}
```